# Create Dynamic Type in C# for Dapper

Tags: c#, dapper

I have an application in which I'm saving unknown structured data. So, let's assume for a moment there is a table in the database named `Foo` and it looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Foo]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [DataId] INT NOT NULL, 
    [Bar] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Foo_Data] FOREIGN KEY ([DataId]) REFERENCES [Data]([Id])
)
```

And `Foo` is related to a table named `Data` which is going to store the provider who logged the data as well as the date and time it was logged, and let's say that table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Data]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [ProviderId] INT NOT NULL, 
    [RecordDateTime] DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Data_Provider] FOREIGN KEY ([ProviderId]) REFERENCES [Provider]([Id])
)
```

Okay, now let's assume that the provider (which I have no knowledge of the data it's providing) has a class named `Foo` that looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class Foo : ISerializable
{
    private string bar;

    public string Bar
    {
        get { return bar; }
        set { bar = value; }
    }

    public Foo()
    {
        Bar = "Hello World!";
    }

    public Foo(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        this.bar = info.GetString("Bar");
    } 

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("Bar", bar);
    }
}
```

So, when the provider sends me an instance of `Foo` I'm going to interrogate it and determine which table in the database it should be inserted into, and let's assume that code block looks like this:

```
this.connection.Open();

try
{
    var parameters = new
        {
            ProviderId = registeredProvidersIdBySession[providerKey.ToString()],
            RecordDateTime = DateTime.Now,
        };

    var id = connection.Query<int>("INSERT INTO Data (ProviderId, RecordDateTime) VALUES (@ProviderId, @RecordDateTime); SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as INT)", parameters).Single();

    var t = data.GetType();
    var fields = t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    var tableName = string.Format("[{0}]", t.Name);
    var fieldList = string.Join(", ", fields.Select(p => string.Format("[{0}]", p.Name)).ToArray());

    var valueList = fields.Select(p => string.Format("@{0}", p.Name)).ToList();
    valueList.Insert(0, "@DataId");

    var values = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    values.Add("@DataId", id);
    foreach (var propertyInfo in fields)
    {
        values.Add(string.Format("@{0}", propertyInfo.Name), propertyInfo.GetValue(data, null));
    }

    return connection.Execute(string.Format(
        "INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ({2})",
            tableName,
            fieldList,
            string.Join(", ", valueList.ToArray())), values);
}
finally
{
    this.connection.Close();
}
```

Now as you can see, I'm getting the `tableName` from the `Type` of the object passed to me. In our example that's `Foo`. Further, I'm gathering the list of fields to insert with reflection. However, the hitch in the get along is that `Dapper` requires an object be sent to it for the parameter values. Now, if I didn't need to provide the `DataId` property on the type I could just pass in the object that was given to me, but I need that `DataId` property so I can relate the log correctly.

### What am I Asking?

1. Am I going to have to create a dynamic type or can `Dapper` do something else to help?
2. If I'm going to have to create a dynamic type, is there a more straight forward way than using the `TypeBuilder`? I've done it before, and can do it again, but man it's a pain.
3. If I'm going to have to use the `TypeBuilder` I'd be interested in your example because you may know of a more efficient way than I do. So please include an example if you have some thoughts.

### DISCLAIMER

In the code example above you see I tried passing in a `Dictionary<string, object>` instead but `Dapper` doesn't accept that. I pretty much knew it wouldn't because I'd already looked at the source code, but I was just hoping I missed something.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a BuiltIn type in Dapper to pass parameter which properties are known runtime only:
check the class `DynamicParameters`. It is used like:

```
var p = new DynamicParameters();
p.Add("@a", 11);
p.Add("@b", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
p.Add("@c", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
```

and then passed as a parameter object to the `Execute` method. It is typically used with SP ( so you can use it also for reading the output values) but there are no reasons preventing it to work with regular SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE queries.

Comment: And this is why I asked the question, I really didn't want to go down the road of emitting IL if I didn't need to and it seemed like with the caliber of folks that contribute to `Dapper` there should have been a way. Thanks Felice!

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked about dapper but...

Sauce DB actually handles this type of scenario pretty well.  There are a few ways you can do it.  Below is some example code that illustrates it.  Note: you can override how the table name is found and there are method that allow you to retrieve the resolved table name if you wish.

Disclamer: I wrote SauceDB

```
public class Foo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    publi string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    publi string Name { get; set; }
}

public class  MainClass
{
    IDataStore _dstore;
    public void Main()
    {
        _dstore = new SqlServerDataStore("my_connection_string")//create data store

        InsertObject(new Foo());
        InsertObject(new Bar());
    }

    public void InsertObject(object o)
    {
        //this will assume the table it belongs to is the type name + an s
            //you can override the table name behavior as well
        _dstore.InsertObject(o);
    }
}
```

http://sauce.codeplex.com/